# Finding posts that contain a word in the post title from MySQL query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a simple (right now) search function on my site where a user can input a string and then get back results if the post title contains any of the words in the search string. The problem I have is how to handle when user searches for words that can be in other words, then the results should only be the ones containing the specific word. Let me explain with an example:

User search string:

```
"Hi everyone"
```

Some post titles:

```
"Title1 hi"
"Title2 hint"
```

In this case I want the results to only find the first post since it contains "hi" but not the second one since it only contains hi in "hint". There is also the problem when there are titles that looks like this:

```
"Title3 hi, more text"
```

This should also be a result from the user search since the word hi is alone (but with a comma, dot or other sign, in front or in back of the word).

Right now I have a basic query in PHP which adds on the following for each word:

```
AND (posts.post_title LIKE '%".$data->searchString."%')
```

This will of course include all the posts from above. I thought about doing it like this to include most cases:

```
AND (posts.post_title LIKE '% ".$data->searchString." %' OR 
     posts.post_title LIKE '%,".$data->searchString." %' OR
     posts.post_title LIKE '% ".$data->searchString.",%')
```

But I guess this will be very heavy with lots of search words.

**How can I write an efficient query to just get the results I want as given ffrom explanation above?**

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using REGEXP:

```
... posts.post_title REGEXP '\\b[^a-zA-Z0-9]*searchWord[^a-zA-Z0-9]*([^a-zA-Z0-9]|$)';
```

This will delete all non alphanumerical values that are present in front of or behind the search word.